# UISegmentedControl not changing when state change occurs

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, segmentedcontrol

Below I have the code for my picker:

```
struct pickerSwitch: View {
  @ObservedObject var appState: AppState
  @State var selection: String = "Red"
  var colors = ["Red", "Blue"]

  init(appState: AppState) {
        print("Init ran again")
        self.appState = appState
        if appState.showBlueControl {
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)], for: .normal)
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue
        } else {
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)], for: .normal)
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = .red
        }
    }

  var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("")) {
            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
  }
}
```

Elsewhere in my code, I have a button that changes the value of 'showBlueControl' for the specific instance of 'AppState.' In my Xcode logs, I see lots of the 'Init ran again' log so I thought the segmented control should be changing but for some reason the change only takes places when I close the view entirely and reopen it. How can I dynamically change the SegmentedControl when there is a SwiftUI state change (w/o closing/reopening the view)?

Comment: Where are you updating appState  on segment change?

Comment: You can recreate your view by ```.id(selection)``` or by ```.id(appState.showBlueControl)```

Comment: Appending .id(selection) didn't work but using .id(appState.showBlueControl) did--thank you!

Comment: What Is AppState? You really need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: keep in mind: by using this you are creating a whole view again.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer to use [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) for this rather than changing the `id(_:)` of the view. It wouldn't re-init the view on every update (which otherwise may lead to strange bugs later...) and also the styling only affects just this one `Picker` - not every single one throughout the whole app. If you would like me to write up an answer for this, I'm happy to.

Comment: Are you actually trying to modify AppState or do you just want to change the background color of your picker when the value changes?

Comment: @Yrb AppState is just a class that contains all variables that change the state of the app (each view in my app follows AppState and changes accordingly when its variables change). I was just trying to change the background color of the picker when the showBlueControl (in appState instance) value changes.

Comment: @George_E Introspect looks like a great module--I'd love to see an answer using it (and I think it would be good for future viewers to see multiple ways of doing this)

Comment: @nickcoding2 Sure! I have written an answer now for using Introspect, hopefully it's useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an `@State` to keep track of the background color. Then you set the `.background()` on the picker. To change your state variable, simply use `.onChange`.

```
struct PickerSwitch: View {
    @State var selection: String = "Red"
    var colors = ["Red", "Blue"]
    @State var backgroundColor = Color.red // This tracks your background color
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("")) {
            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
// .onChange reacts to the change of selection
        .onChange(of: selection, perform: { value in 
            if value == "Red" {
                backgroundColor = .red
            } else {
                backgroundColor = .blue
            }
        })
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        .background(backgroundColor) // Set your background color here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect). I prefer this rather than changing the `.id(_:)` of the view, because:

When you change the ID of a view, you are causing it to be invalidated and then therefore recreated. It can also lead to some strange bugs such as the animation stopping weirdly, and inability to change tab mid-way through to interrupt the animation. However, with Introspect, the view doesn't get reinitialized. The view body just gets updated when `appState` changes.

Also, with Introspect the styling only affects just this one `Picker` - not every-single-one throughout the whole app.

I also simplified how you deal with keeping track of the colors. Note that we bind to the selected color with `$appState.switchColor`.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var appState = AppState()

    var body: some View {
        PickerSwitch(appState: appState)
    }
}
```

```
enum SwitchColor: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case red = "Red"
    case blue = "Blue"

    var id: String { rawValue }

    var color: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .red: return .red
        case .blue: return .blue
        }
    }
}

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var switchColor: SwitchColor = .red
}
```

```
struct PickerSwitch: View {
    @ObservedObject var appState: AppState

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Select color", selection: $appState.switchColor) {
            ForEach(SwitchColor.allCases) { color in
                Text(color.rawValue).tag(color)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        .introspectSegmentedControl { segmentedControl in
            let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)]
            segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
            segmentedControl.backgroundColor = appState.switchColor.color
        }
    }
}
```